# Re compile stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have added non-clustered index to some tables,

Do I need to re-start, or recompile all of the stored procedure to get benefit of the new indexes.

And how to do so?

Comment: See [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840719/add-sql-server-index-but-how-to-recompile-only-affected-stored-procedures)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do we need to Recompile all stored procedures when indexes rebuild happen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509579/do-we-need-to-recompile-all-stored-procedures-when-indexes-rebuild-happen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to. When the stored procedure will try to fetch data from you tables the query optimizer will see that there is an index to some of your tables and it will build the corresponding execution plan, which then it will be passed to execution engine, in order to be executed.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The most that you might have to do is to flush the cached query plans with `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - My thoughts too until I read the BOL quote on the [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4509615/73226). Any idea what that is talking about? It is contradicted by testing and the 2008 [plan caching white paper](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx) which states "Adding an index to a table or an indexed view." will cause a recompile.

Comment: sql internals says ..."Adding an index to a table or an indexed view... is a cause of correctness recompile (p543). BOL no up to date?

Comment: @Alain_Deloin - That's my conclusion. [Have raised it on Connect here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/809771/recompile-a-stored-procedure-topic-contains-incorrect-assertion)

Comment: @MartinSmith I think its an incorrect conclusion drawn from an incomplete description/understanding.  I.E., it's just wrong. ... I upvoted your connect post as well.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Microsoft responded that the documentation is indeed wrong and will be corrected.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You will need to re-compile your stored procedures to take advantage of new indexes.

There is a full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509579/do-we-need-to-recompile-all-stored-procedures-when-indexes-rebuild-happen)

Comment: Yes,,in my end it is using the indexes..just not sure how will it behave in production

Comment: @Akon - I edited my answer as I was wrong ! Check out the link.

Answer (score -1):

you need to recompile your stored procedures (triggers, functions), but you you don't need to do it one by one, you can use `sp_recompile 'TableName'` and SQL will recompile all stored procedures, triggers that references your table and get benefits of your new index (and you won't miss one).

Followup: i leave my post -it is still the BOL answer- but the correct answer seems to be : No you don't  (see other post)